# PHP Get contents of webpage JSON

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents, coinbase-api

After running the code below, I get a empty page. I would like to get the price from bids and asks, but I can't get any data.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $url="https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-EUR/book"; 
    $json = @file_get_contents($url);
    if($json){
        $data = @json_decode($json, TRUE);
        print_r($data);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well, for starters, stop suppressing errors with `@`. Turning on `display_errors` is pointless if you then suppress the errors.

Comment: Empty page typically means an error without display errors on, or with the error supressed, as Ed states. ```file_get_contents``` will fail on external URLs on certain servers. Use CURL instead.

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/BTC-EUR/book): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in X on line 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that this API appears to be blocking these types of requests. They will not allow users that do not have a useragent set.

The fastest way to get around this is to set a UserAgent within PHP, which you can do by putting this code above your call to the API:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0');
```

However, I would recommend using CURL instead of file_get_contents, as file_get_contents is often restricted by server configuration.